last_sign_in is missing for Autodesk Construction Cloud users
When fetching users from the Account users endpoint in ACC (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/users-GET/), last_sign_in is empty for most users, although we know that users are actually signing-in and using the platform (probably through BIM 360).
I found this question from 9 months ago that describes a similar issue - Last_sign_in value not updated for ACC, only BIM 360

Is there any other way to retrieve reliable sign-in information from Autodesk API?
Is there an ETA for populating last_sign_in for users who are accessing ACC and not BIM 360?
Do we have that information available in Data connector API?


The issue stands as per the discussion on the thread: Last_sign_in value not updated for ACC, only BIM 360.
We don't track last sign in for ACC apps currently.
last_sign-in is updated when a user logs into any of the following services on the web:

(BIM 360) Account Admin
(BIM 360) Project Admin
Document Management
Classic Field
Classic Plan

No other services update last_sign-in at this time.
The team is making efforts to have this resolved and aligned . I will be making close follow up on the progress for the tickets logged: AECP-879, ACSFR-775 and revert soon as we have an update. We apologise for this gap and request your patience

Hi Carol, are there any updates that you can share?

Hello Gili, unfortunately no updates on this item yet
